# How do I calculate a field in all documents based on a value of a particular document in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, collections, pymongo, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am new to MongoDb and trying  to achieve some basic calculation in it. I have collection, calc, as below

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10}
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 20}
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 20}
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 30}
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : 30}
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : 30}
```

I want to add the value of "_id":1 to all value field of the documents in that collection and create a new field with the calculated result. So the final result I am looking for is as below.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10, "sumup":20 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 20, "sumup":30 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 20, "sumup":30 }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 30, "sumup":40 }
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : 30, "sumup":40 }
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : 30, "sumup":40 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this in mongo shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "value": 1, 
            "sumup": { 
                "$add": [ "$value", (db.collection.findOne({"_id": 1})).value ] 
            } 
        } 
    }
])
```